# how to check a filesystem in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, disk-utility

In Ubuntu 12.04 I was used to run the 'Disk Utility' and choose 'Check Filesystem'; its subtitle showed also 'and repair'. In Ubuntu 16.04 I have only found the 'Disks' utility that looks similarly but has no 'Check Filesystem' option, even for the superuser.

Comment: Great... gnome continues to remove useful features...

Comment: in Ubuntu 18.04, the 'Disks' utility has those options again (Check Filesystem and Repair Filesystem).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Now I urgently need to repair partitions at an USB disk and at a  flash disk. I am in a great time span and I can not afford a mistake by inventing the right commands. I beg you to tell me the commands for a partition mounted as /media/my_user/kus. I hope I can still find the system identifier for the partition. Thanks!

Comment: I can also use Ubuntu 12.04 at an old Pentium IV PC. Some things still work OK there. Which of it do you see as a more safe? Thanks!

Comment: @TomášPečený the instructions that I gave should work in most situations. What part are you having difficulty with? Your USB disk, if it's an external, is probably /dev/sdb{something}, so the fsck command would be `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb{something}`.

Comment: @TomášPečenýfsck is for ext4 linux partitions. You're trying to repair a fat partition. Either you've selected the wrong partition number to fix, or you're trying to repair a problem that requires `chkdsk` under Windows to repair.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to write, than hesitated how to format, but the page took it as a comment. It appears that all is OK as I will write in further at least two comments

Comment: After restarting the PC, i see the maybe lost files in my /dev/sdd2 external USB partition. First, I have not unmounted that partition while using the 'Disks' utility. The system answered
'0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.' I have chosen 'No action'.

Comment: The system answered 'There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)'. I have chosen 'No action'. Then I have unmounted it in the 'Disks' utility and repeated the 'sudo fsck -f /dev/sdd2' command. I have got '/dev/sdd2: 75173 files, 2390429/10138612 clusters' and I hope it is OK.
Probably I should have closed the 'Disks' utility after I have read the partition name.

Comment: Among the system answers, also 'fsck from util-linux 2.27.1' and '
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)' appeared and I hope that also FAT32 partition
may be checked this way.

Comment: The question about formatting was https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17399/in-comments-how-to-write-blocs-of-commands

Answer (score 1):

Just some comments:

1. To enter the GRUB menu press and hold SHIFT while booting
2. In Recovery Mode better to choose "fsck - Check all file systems", see picture.

[image]

Great description here: [How to Use ‘fsck’ to Repair File System Errors in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/)