# Trying to repair LVM disk with fsck

Tags: fsck

I'm on Ubuntu 16, and I'm trying to repair my startup disk. I have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953728/how-to-check-a-filesystem-in-ubuntu-16-04/953750), but once I'm at the root access of Recovery mode, it still says that the disk is mounted and it can't run.
If I try `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3`, it just replies:

`fsck from util-linux`.
Anyone know why it might do that? According [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479859/ubuntu-recovery-says-fsck-from-util-linux-and-exits), when fsck reports this command, you have to use fsck.ext4. However, when I do that, I still get a message about the volume being in use.

I see there's [another question about this on Ubuntu 18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090066/cant-run-fsck-in-recovery-mode-in-18-10-disk-is-mounted-r-w), but there's no answer.

Most answers suggest using a Live Disk, but Etcher isn't working on MacOS at the moment, and it's surely not unreasonable to get this done from the recovery command prompt.

It's a vanilla Ubuntu install on a Dell Inspiron laptop.

Performing `umount /dev/sda3` gives me "/dev/sda3 not mounted."
Performing `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda3` gives me "/dev/sda3 is in use".

The output of lsblk /dev/sda gives:

```
sda                     disk
   sda2                 part
   sda3                 part
      ubuntu--vg-root   lvm   /
   sda1                 part
```

*(obviously, I'm typing this in on another computer)* I've left out the sizes, hope that's clear.

I've also tried `umount -lf /`. After doing that, when I run `fsck`, I get a message that it cannot check if the filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file.

Comment: you want to repair the linux's partition ?

Comment: Yes. of course!

Comment: The instructions you linked to have an entire section "If for some reason you can't do the above..." Follow those instructions.

Comment: So there's no way of repairing the disk without making a Live image on some other disk or DVD? Wow.

Comment: Often such repairs are possible. In your (unusual) case, appears not. We don't know why your case is unusual, since we don't know the history. Wow.

Comment: What would you need to know? It's clearly not that unusual, as there are people asking the question here and elsewhere. It's a bit surprising that there aren't general steps to ensure that you can fsck a disk.

Comment: Partition needs to be unmounted, that is why live installer is normally suggested. But if you can boot recovery mode then you can run fsck from that with partition(s) unmounted.

Comment: @oldfred Any advice on how to unmount it? I've had no luck.

Comment: You might want to see https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/problem-running-fsck-on-lvm-642750/ as you need the Volume name to check with fsck.  It should be the same commands for checking LVM

Comment: @Terrance Thanks, but I'm having trouble comprehending that page. I've tried `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/ubuntu-vg-root` (based on the output of pvscan) but it gives no such device.

Comment: I had to sit myself in front of a system to get a good answer for you.  I ended up removing my previous comments as at this point they are not needed.  It can be difficult to come up with an answer if I am not seeing what you are seeing.  Glad I was able to come up with something that could help you!  =)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To check the LVM it is done with the following steps.

First we can see our drive layout with `lsblk`:

```
# lsblk
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0    20G  0 disk  
└─sda1                 8:1    0    20G  0 part  
  └─xubuntu--vg-root 253:0    0    19G  0 lvm   / 
sr0                   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

as we can see the LVM is named `xubuntu--vg-root`, but we cannot run `fsck` on this name as it will not find it.  We need to get the whole name.  To do this we are going to run the `lvm lvscan` command to get the LV name so we can run `fsck` on the LVM.

*The following commands should be ran as `sudo` or as a `root` user.*

```
# lvscan
  inactive          '/dev/xubuntu-vg/root' [<19.04 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/xubuntu-vg/swap_1' [980.00 MiB] inherit
```

As we can see our name to check is `/dev/xubuntu-vg/root` so we should be able to run `fsck` on that name

If the `/dev/xubuntu-vg/root` is not `ACTIVE`, we need to make it active so that we can run the check on it

```
lvchange -ay /dev/xubuntu-vg/root
```

Now it should look like this:

```
# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/xubuntu-vg/root' [<19.04 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/xubuntu-vg/swap_1' [980.00 MiB] inherit
```

Now we can run the `fsck` on the LVM volume.

```
fsck /dev/xubuntu-vg/root
```

or to run a forced check with assume yes

```
fsck -fy /dev/xubuntu-vg/root
```

*Adding a screen shot since VirtualBox will not let me copy and paste.*

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Comment: @benwiggy you should award the bounty.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I thought that happened automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this command:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda6
```

assuming Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: Please see my question. I've tried that exact command (with sda3, which is where Ubuntu is), and I get a message that it is in use.

Comment: mount it before doing anything (use the mount command with the ds3 partition) and then you can use the command that i gave to u

Comment: So, I should mount a volume that is already mounted, and then unmount it with a command that already doesn't work?

Comment: try `sudo mount -o remount,ro /` ... if this doesn't work, then something is running off the root partition and you are not in the proper recovery mode..