# Can't fsck, can't figure out why and I need my files

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem, fsck

I need to fsck my drive, It boots saying i need to manually run fsck on ubuntu-studio-vg-root , fsck exited with status code 4, so I booted from livecd and went to run it, I have ubuntu studio 18.4  this is what i got

```
~ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ lsblk

NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 308/124928 files (17.2% non-contiguous), 134315/498688 blocks

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda1: clean, 308/124928 files, 134315/498688 blocks
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ unmount /dev/sda5

Command 'unmount' not found, did you mean:

  command 'umount' from deb mount

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda5
umount: /dev/sda5: not mounted.
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda1
umount: /dev/sda1: not mounted.

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda1: 308/124928 files (17.2% non-contiguous), 134315/498688 blocks

~ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda1: clean, 308/124928 files, 134315/498688 blocks

ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sda5
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda5 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ umount /dev/sda5
umount: /dev/sda5: not mounted.
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ umount /dev/sda2
umount: /dev/sda2: not mounted.

 - 


----------


ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo swapoff
swapoff: bad usage
Try 'swapoff --help' for more information.
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ swapoff --help

Usage:
 swapoff [options] [<spec>]

Disable devices and files for paging and swapping.

Options:
 -a, --all              disable all swaps from /proc/swaps
 -v, --verbose          verbose mode

 -h, --help             display this help
 -V, --version          display version

The <spec> parameter:
 -L <label>             LABEL of device to be used
 -U <uuid>              UUID of device to be used
 LABEL=<label>          LABEL of device to be used
 UUID=<uuid>            UUID of device to be used
 <device>               name of device to be used
 <file>                 name of file to be used

For more details see swapoff(8).
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$
```

---

I went though gparted and couldn't post a screenshot because this site is dumb but, there's a little gray down arrow next to /dev/sda2 but i doesn't   say it's mounted
it says dev/sda5 is in use even though it's unmounted,can someone please help me though this? i'm a noob and really need to save my files from this drive

Comment: @guiverc 18.04 it was a typo

Comment: @Terrance is it ok to run that from on terminal on cd?

Comment: @Terrance Am I supposed to run as sudo? this happened   ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ lvm lvscan
  WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: access failed: Permission denied
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  /dev/mapper/control: open failed: Permission denied
  Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
  Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.145 (2017-11-03) and kernel driver (unknown version).

Comment: @Terrance If its active I just skip the step to make it active right? $ sudo lvm lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-studio-vg/root' [<923.08 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-studio-vg/swap_1' [7.95 GiB] inherit

Comment: @Terrance is this okay? im not deleting files right?
Entry '08F8748DF1900A51196D40DB4B11DD7F4F28D12C' in /home/spoons/.cache/mozilla/firefox/c60y3wmz.default/cache2/entries (30408818) has deleted/unused inode 30440874.  Clear<y>?

Comment: @Terrance okay, does this mean if i reboot it will work?/dev/mapper/ubuntu--studio--vg-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--studio--vg-root: 419966/60497920 files (1.4% non-contiguous), 22454901/241979392 blocks

Comment: @Terrance okay, Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome!  If it worked, we should remove all of these comments.  Then for procedural purposes since that answer helped, your question should be closed as a duplicate, but that is OK to help others if they experience the same thing you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to repair LVM disk with fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124500/trying-to-repair-lvm-disk-with-fsck)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It sounds like your issue was related to the called duplicate by @Terrance but it's hard to tell by your question. [edit]ing the output of `mount -l` into your post should make that clearer.