# Ubuntu 22.04 boot problem

Tags: 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly won't boot. The message reads:"The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck"
Can it be saved? If so, how.

Comment: Is it also encrypted? Old instructions, change to what your scan shows, & do not run the resize commands. https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu

Comment: No encryption. Do I have a disk problem?

Comment: You have a disk problem, but it may be solvable. Boot into rescue mode, unmount your root filesystem, and run `fsck -N /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` (this can take a while). This will tell you what the situation is and what needs to be done, but it won't make any changes.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124500/trying-to-repair-lvm-disk-with-fsck/1125166#1125166  to run FSCK on your LVM drive.

Comment: Thanks much, but I replaced the disk and am starting over. Years of stuff...Oh well.