Stuck in GRUB 2.06 command line after copying disk with CloneZilla
I have two identical HDD disks both have the same size. Because my main disk had some bad sectors, I decided to move my Ubuntu 22.04 system to another newer disk. Following the advice of people on this site I copied my disk using CloneZilla in disk-to-disk mode, with rescue checked. But now when I start the new disk, I get stuck at the GRUB 2.06 command line.
Using the information from this question:
Stuck at GRUB command line
I tried to find the grub folder on my system and run it through the console, but the grub folder is inaccessible as it is encrypted for some reason.
The ls command gives me this:
(proc) (memdisk) (lvm/vgubuntu-swap-1) (lvm/vgubuntu-root) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
When I try to ls (lvm/vgubuntu-swap-1), (hd0) and (hd0,gpt2) or (hd0,2) it tells me error: unknown filesystem
ls (hd0,gpt1) or (hd0,1) gives me an efi/ folder with ubuntu and boot in it. There is no grub in either of them.
In efi/ubuntu only the files grubx64.efi shimx64.efi mmx64.efi bootx64.cvs grub.cfg
And in efi/boot the files fbx64.efi mmx64.efi mmx64.efi bkpbootx64.efi bootx64.efi
I tried putting both in set prefix
ls (lvm/vgubuntu-root)/ gives a different result, it shows a normal system with dev, root, boot, home, and other folders. I know that in (lvm/vgubuntu-root)/boot there is a grub folder that can be specified in the set prefix that will work, since I checked it on the original system. But on the copy instead of letting me go deeper I get error: directory is encrypted because of which set prefix and set root for (lvm/vgubuntu-root)/root don't work (root is encrypted too). I checked them on the original disk and everything worked properly.
boot-repair doesn't give me a repair button, either on its own iso or on Ubuntu on a flash drive.
The BIOS says the disk is UEFI. Both disks are not connected at the same time and I don't have a second OS on the same disk.
I can't just reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, as I have a lot of other programs on there that I've been struggling with.
UPD: Secure boot is also off.
UPD2: BootInfo summary report https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mtvnbwJpjJ/

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ I have always preferred a new install & restore from backup. Backup should allow you to restore system within about an hour. If not your backup is not complete. And any repair that takes more than an hour, then should be the new install.

@oldfred Ah, I knew I was forgetting something. I updated the question, added a link to BootInfo summary report.

Pastebin must be having an issue, you are second one with pastebin software error.

Pastebin working. You show UEFI boot from UUID that does not exist. See line 180 and list of UUIDs on line 144. Total reinstall of grub should fix that or manually go into ESP - efi system partition and update UUID & drive to hd0.

@oldfred
I can't reinstall grub because I can't even mount /dev/vgubuntu/root and swap_1. It tells me wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. However, I was able to mount and open /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg in ESP to change everything properly. Unfortunately nothing worked. When I use normal in GRUB 2.06 it starts thinking for a second and just restarts GRUB 2.06.
None of these problems are present on the original disk.

Can you use live installer and mount LVM? sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124500/trying-to-repair-lvm-disk-with-fsck
