# keep having fsck error on boot, also the reinstllation of any Ubuntu version gets stuck

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, ssd, hardware, fsck

I am using a dual boot laptop with ubuntu 18.04.3 lts and windows 10.
For some unknown reason after an ubuntu update and system restart I got the following error:

```
/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

I tried the "fsck /dev/sda6" command, but after a reboot now I fall into the emergency mode:

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into dafault mode. Press Enter for maintenance (or press control-D to continue):
```

or a similar message which indicates I am in the emergency mode, sometimes after some restarts then again I get the "fsck exited with status code 4" error. Basically I am stuck in these two conditions (now thw emergency mode) and I cannot find any way out of it.

I even tried to reinstall the Ubuntu 18.04.3 but it stucks on “Updates and Other Software” window! I even tried the ubuntu 16 but it again stuck on the "Preparing to install Ubuntu"  !!

I even tried the installation with "nomodeset" and "Acpi=off" options, no success!

I suppose something could have gone wrong in the update phase (**maybe a sudden power rest**). My main worry is I cannot even log into the windows and access my windows drives,so first I would want to get the data backed up and then fix the issue.
Any idea is appreciated

**Update1:**

I managed to recover my data. I took out the hard drive and used a hard drive enclosure and connected the hard drive via a USB cable to another computer. In this process, I noticed something interesting, first I tried Windows10 to copy the files but windows had a hard time recognize the disk and displaying the files and it got stuck easily, then I tried an Ubuntu 19 live USB and I managed to copy my data. Can corruption of system files lead to such conditions?

**Update2:**

I tried the `fsck -y /dev/sda6`command (this time with -y option) it seems it went one step ahead as it ended with :

```
/dev/sdb6: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb6: 306623/3057824 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 3733827/12231201 blocks
```

However, after the reboot, I again fell into the emergency mode , and the output of the `journalctl -xb` command is a long log (1364 lines), in which I think the followings line could be notable :

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1026040 flags 80700
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xB000B0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0 
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x400000008
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC }

// and more errors similar to the above

Failed to start AppArmor Initialization  //last error
```

I don't know a way to extract the whole log in such condition lemme know plz if there is a way.

**Update3:**

The SMART **status of the hard drive** using the ubuntu live, disk utility was showing "Disk is OK", but suddenly it has changed to "Failed". 
considering the fact that I still can access my data on all drives except the ubuntu drive, I assume **some important file systems are corrupted,** which stops me from either booting the Ubuntu or Windows operating systems. However, I have no idea if there is a fix for it or I need to change the hard drive.

Moreover, I tried another ssd into my laptop and this time it allowed me to install Ubuntu did not stuck in the installation phase. So something should have gone wrong with my hard drive but I am not sure whether it is at hardware level or software level or can it be fixed or I should replace the hard drive.

Comment: Look up how to run a SMART test on your hard drive. You are describing common symptoms of a dying hard drive. the SMART test will confirm or rule out a hardware fault.

Comment: @JS32 Can you provide the reference of your computer (model and constructor) ? Some constructors are trying to block users to install dual boots.

Comment: My computer is old, I don't think blocking is the problem, I have had a dual boot for a couple of years, just recently I upgraded to the version 18.04 and the only problem that I had was with the Nvidia graphic driver.

Comment: Try to avoid ranting like "*I am pretty sure the ubuntu killed it !*" It reduces the number of folks willing to help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This sounds like a hardware problem to me, but if you [edit] the output of the suggested `journalctl -xb` into your question we wouldn't have to guess. Please do so and thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @user535733 Maybe I was not clear enough or maybe you got me wrong, anyways. I said "IF the hard drive is dead", I meant it is extremely unlikely that the hard drive is dead, as the problem raised from the ubuntu update. And it is not really possible that ubuntu damaged the hard disk! am I right? (Moreover, I recovered my data from the data hard drive so I don't think it is dead at least not completely, read my answer to Elder plz)

Comment: What [fsck exit status 4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107876/fsck-died-with-status-code-4) means.

Comment: Insufficient data to localize the issue, which means that it's not likely to be useful to future readers. I/O errors could have many possible, most of which are hardware faults - Ubuntu cannot fix or work around broken hardware. Could be the disk (your SMART test ruled this out), the motherboard, the power supply, the cabling, etc.

Comment: You have two conflicting data points: Assuming it was read properly, your SMART test apparently says "no hardware issue", your log seems to say "likely hardware issue". We are, regrettably, not psychic: We don't know which is correct, nor why one seems to be incorrect. That's why there is insufficient data for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I can say with a high degree of certainty that this problem has nothing to do with your graphics card.

If the Ubuntu Live media doesn't show those drives, odds are good they aren't being detected by your system (BIOS or EFI) either. This means the drive(s) in question are shot **unless replacing the cables** does the trick. If not, you have limited options to get your data back:

1. restore from [backup](https://askubuntu.com/q/569679/225694)
2. if your handy, find an identical donor drive and try replacing the circuit board of the failed drive and pray.
3. Ship the drive to a data recovery service company and pray. (This will be expensive)

In future consider the importance of backing up data that you don't wish to lose. There are a number of strategies [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/569679/225694) and a number of tools mentioned [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I managed to recover my data. I took out the hard drive and used a hard drive enclosure and connected the hard drive via a USB cable to another computer (I don't know if this is as same as your 2nd option or not).

Moreover, when I boot into the BIOS, in the main system summary, in front of the Hard Disk Drive I can see the capacity (1000GB), so I assume it is detected.

Comment: @JS32 I'm glad you got it sorted. based on your output and results the problem was likely a bad cable (which you bypassed by moving to an external enclosure). Cheers!

Comment: I actually do not think that the problem was a bad cable! I tried another ssd into my laptop (so using the same cables) and this time it allowed me to install the Ubuntu! So no stuck in the installation phase, I think some important file systems are corupted but I have no idea whether there is a fix for it or not

Comment: @JS32 You bring up a valid point, however I have yet to see hard drive cables in a laptop. Regardless, it seems clear that you had a connectivity problem that in a desktop you could feasibly resolve by replacing the data cable or in a laptop by re-seating the drive in it's connector. Since you replaced the SSD and were able to install to it that would appear to rule out any issues with the laptop mainboard. Since you were able to recover the data via external enclosure it seems doubtful that the filesystem was corrupted. The fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/953750/225694