# not booting.kernel panic

Tags: boot, kernel

[image: Kernel Panic Boot error]

On reboot the above image error is shown. Machine was clean shutdown yesterday. Today during reboot there was automatic BIOS update. After this when tried to reboot, the error is shown. How to rectify this?

> OS : Ubuntu 23.04
>
> Desktop

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    276021 Aug 14 16:59 config-6.2.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    276021 Aug 14 14:07 config-6.2.0-32-generic
drwx------  4 root root      4096 Jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Sep  9 15:38 grub/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        27 Sep  5 10:14 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 127978381 Aug 30 10:06 initrd.img-6.2.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 128301803 Sep  9 16:16 initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        27 Sep  5 10:14 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-6.2.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    138712 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+ia32.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    139776 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+ia32.efi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    144312 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+x64.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    145408 Feb 11  2023 memtest86+x64.efi
-rw-------  1 root root   8167532 Aug 14 16:59 System.map-6.2.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   8168955 Aug 14 14:07 System.map-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        24 Sep  5 10:14 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  13829480 Aug 14 17:32 vmlinuz-6.2.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  13833896 Aug 14 14:08 vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        24 Sep  5 10:14 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-31-generic

sudo fsck -f /
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
/dev/sda3 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Sometimes through GRUB i can do recovery. Doesn't work everytime though

Comment: You've provided few specifics; but from your picture; I'd boot *live* media & check the health of your system.  You gave no details as to if anything occurred before hand (*which is key details; eg. power loss, forced unclean shutdown etc*), thus I'd be checking hardware for problems first (PSU, RAM, disk health using SMART etc), then move to file-system checks. If the file-system checks detected & corrected issues; I'd expect normal operation on next boot; however the issue I'd be interested in is WHY did you this occur, and is this a symptom of a hardware problem or other..

Comment: how to perform the checks?

Comment: You provided few specifics (ie. no OS/release, no clues if desktop, server, no clues as to file-system as file-system check commands vary on file-system being used).  The following maybe helpful; eg. for disk health checks & SMART see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools , for file-system checks see https://askubuntu.com/questions/953728/how-to-check-a-filesystem-in-ubuntu-16-04  (but do NOTE `fsck` or file-system check will only check some file-system types, so adjust command to match your *unstated* file-system(s)

Comment: can you guide me what all details are needed and how to get them

Comment: If you can get it into recovery mode, I would try running `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to rebuild the `init` part that may be missing from the kernel(s).

Comment: Already ran the same, but instead of 'all' did $(uname - r)

Comment: Please add things like that to your question so that we are not guessing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to invoke `grub` (press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> when boot starts) and use another kernel. If it helps - then it's something wrong with the kernel you try to boot.

I had similar situation. The reason was lack of memory in the `/boot` folder, which is why kernel was not installed properly. Deleting old kernels was the solution.

Comment: There is another version shown in grub menu,even tat is showing same error